# What type of Arduino to buy

Tags: rgb-led, stepper-motor

I am doing a project for school to run 462 LEDs in 6 series (77 each) and a stepper motor altogether, I wanna know what model of Arduino I should buy (not so expensive)? 
I am using individually addressable WS2812B RGB LED strips ...
So it should be controlled in 6 groups of 77 LEDs in each group. 
[image]

Comment: Are the LEDs build into a strip or just simple LEDs? If the former: What type of strip/LEDs to you have? Should every LED be controlled individually or together in groups?

Comment: Can you give more details. It is hard to recommend a board with so little details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these requirements you can use most available Arduinos. The WS2812 LED strips need 1 pin per strip (or 1 pin in total, if you daisy-chain all the strips, meaning connecting the data lines of them to one big strip). How many pins you need for the stepper motor depends on the type of motor and what type of driver you have for it. Most stepper drivers need 2 digital pins from your Arduino (1 direction pin and 1 pulse pin). There are also cheap drivers based on the ULN2003 chip, where you have to control the phases directly, needing 4 pins.

You should also buy an Arduino, that leaves you a big headroom to develop your project further, if you want.

An Arduino Uno or Nano would be good fitting for this project (though smaller Arduinos like the Pro Micro also would work). If you are able to order them over sites like Aliexpress directly from china (and if you are ok with a longer shipping time), you can get Nanos for 1 - 2$.

---

Since you have many LEDs, you really have to consider your power supply. 462 LEDs, which need up to 60mA each (20mA for each colour in full brightness), means you need at least a 28A power supply (in total). And don't draw the LED current through the Arduino, or you will fry it's voltage regulator or diode.

Comment: I corrected the needed current for the supply XD 28A instead of 2,8A

Comment: And you might want to look at [this guide from Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/the-magic-of-neopixels). It describes, how you use the WS2812 LEDs and what you have to consider.

Comment: I need two pins for stepper Nema 17, and the driver is DRV8825 Stepper Driver ...

Comment: The power supply is old pc power supply Model LPG12 550W ATX Computer Power Supply Desktop PC

Comment: I don't know, if this computer power supply can give you enough current. Source it's datasheet for the current, that you can get out of the 5V pins. 28A is a lot. Be sure to use cables, that are big enough, or they will melt from the current.

Comment: Take care about timing issues such that stepper motor and WS2812 don't interfere.

Answer (score -1):

If that's only 6 on/off (or even fading) LED groups (no RGB-color led stripes) and one stepper motor, any Arduino (Uno / Nano) would do. There are clones, even cheaper than the original.

The peripheral electronics:

- Motor driver
- Transistors to switch the LED (77 standard LED need 1.5 A, so you have to search for Logic Level MOSFET transistors)

are as expensive as the controller itself,
... and wiring all those LEDs is the hardest work.

Comment: The LEDs are WS2812B strips, meaning that you don't need transistors to switch them. The WS2812B is actually the driver chip of each RGB LED in that strip and already consists the needed transistors. You only need to connect the data line to the Arduino

Comment: the 6* 77 is because of the design.